# onClose is not a function for a Modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a Modal and having some issues. I am able to open my Modal, but am unable to close it by clicking outside the "container" id within my Modal.

Home Page

```
const [showMyModal, setShowMyModal] = useState<boolean>(false) 
const handleClose = () => setShowMyModal(false)

const handleOpen = () => setShowMyModal(true)

  return (
    <div className={style.hero}>
      
        <div>
        <h1>Product Page</h1>
        <button onClick={handleOpen} className='bg-red-400 text-white px-3 -y-2 rounded hover:scale-95 tarnsition text-xl'>New Product</button>
        </div>
        { ProductData && <Table columns={columns} dataSource={ProductData.allProducts} />}
        
        <MyModal onClose={handleClose} visible={showMyModal}/>
  
    </div>
  )
```

Modal Code:

```
export default function MyModal({visible}: any, {onClose}: any)  {

    const handleClose =(e:any) => {
      if(e.target.id ==='container') onClose();
    };

    if(!visible) return null

    return (
      <div id='container' onClick={handleClose} className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm flex items-center justify-center">
        //Form is in here
      </div>
    );
}
```

Any assistance would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't know what's the problem with your code
But I used to handle my modal that way

MyModal.tsx

```
interface Modal {
  visible: boolean;
  close: any;
}
export default function MyModal(props: Modal) {
  const handleClose = (e: any) => {
    if (e.target.id === "container") {
      props.close();
    }
  };

  if (!props.visible) return null;

  return (
    <div id="container" onClick={handleClose} className="modal">
      //Form is in here
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can call that way

```
const [showMyModal, setShowMyModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShowMyModal(false);

  const handleOpen = () => setShowMyModal(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Product Page</h1>
        <button
          onClick={handleOpen}
          className="bg-red-400 text-white px-3 -y-2 rounded hover:scale-95 tarnsition text-xl"
        >
          New Product
        </button>
      </div>

      <MyModal {...{ visible: showMyModal, close: handleClose }} />
    </div>
  );
```

here is the link if you want to try it. It's working as you want

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mcclintock-sl5555?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Something is off with props in your modal currently. Instead of `{visible}: any, {onClose}: any` should be `{visible: any, onClose: any}`

Comment: That didn't work :/